# asp.net dynamic user control button click issue

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I made researching about this subject I could not find proper answer.

In my default.aspx page, I have a treeview. Codes are in default.aspx like below:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
 protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Control ucont;
      if (TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value == "Yeni Dönem")
      {
         ucont = LoadControl("usercontrols/yenidonem.ascx");
         PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ucont);
      }
      else
      {
         ucont = LoadControl("usercontrols/tabloktar.ascx");
         PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ucont);
      }
 }
```

I load user controls dnynmicaly. User controls are have button control. I can not fire user control's button click when I load it dynamcally. How can I solve this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not recommend adding control dynamically later than in `Page_Load` event. Other things to remember is that You should add it on each page load and assign unique `ID` value the control that does not change between postbacks.

In this case, the easiest way would be to always add both controls to the page and show appropriate one using `Visibility` property.

If that's not suitable for You, try to move the code  from `TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged` to the `Page_Load` event and load appropriate control on each postback until it should be changed to another one.

I haven't tested this, so if You have any issues when using thise answer, let me know in the comments and I'll try to help.

Comment: But in this case,for every button clcik event or postback inside the usercontroler,It loads the controlss again and again.

Comment: The thing is You need to load the control clicked in the postback generated ***when*** it was clicked, so the appropriate click event can be handled correctly. If You don't load the control then the `Click` event is not fired, because there is no control bound to that event on that particular postback. When You add both controls to the page on each postback, both of them are always loaded, but You can control which one is rendered with `Visibility` property.